# SQLite byte to SQLite File

Tags: python, sqlite, byte, fastapi, file-conversion

I have a .sqlite file that was converted into a byte format, I would like to know how to convert it to a format where I can manipulate the data inside of it, as well as read.

The code is in python and the database is in sqlite.

Anything is helpful! Would like to have a direction to go.

```
b'SQLite format 3\x00\x10\x00\x01\x01\x00@  \x00\x04\xa4\xb2\x00\x00\x0f\xed\x00\x00\x04~\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\xa4\xb2\x00.S`\x05\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x0f\xc9\x00\x00\x00\x08F\x0f\xfb\x0f\xf6\x0f\xf1\x0f\xec\x0f\xe7\x0f\xe2\x0f\xdd\x0f\xd8\x0f\xd3\x0f\xce\x0f\xc9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
```

Comment: [Easy to do in C](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/deserialize.html), but as is all too often the case, the python SQLite bindings don't expose that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's just raw bytes you should be able to save it to a file:

###### 1. Prepare some data

```
$ sqlite3 test.sqlite
SQLite version 3.36.0 2021-06-18 18:36:39
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t1;
1
sqlite> .quit
```

###### 2. Create a new DB file from bytes:

```
>>> db = bytes(open("test.sqlite", "rb").read())
>>> db[:20]
b'SQLite format 3\x00\x10\x00\x01\x01'
>>> open("new.sqlite", "wb").write(db)
8192
```

###### 3. Test

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> con = sqlite3.connect("new.sqlite")
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM t1"): print(row)
... 
(1,)
```

Comment: thank you! it works on my end! very appreciated